# Linux bash script - For loops issues

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm working on a bash script that will add users in a batch process. This code goes as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A script that creates users.

echo "This is a script to create new users on this system."
echo "How many users do you want to add?"
read am
echo " "

for i in {0..$am..1}
do
    echo "Enter a username below:"
    read usern
    sudo useradd $usern

    sudo passwd $usern

    echo " "
    echo "User $am '$usern' added."
done
```

In this case, I wanted to make 4 users. I went through and entered the username "callum3" and set the password as "1234" for ease of login. Once I input everything (correctly, may I add) the terminal window displays the following.

```
User 4 'callum3' added.
```

This shows that my for loop isn't actually working, when I can see nothing wrong with it. I have tried using a while loop with no luck there either.

Am I making a rookie mistake here or is there something deeper going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I suspected it, for a better understanding on what could be wrong with your script I pasted it in [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net). That the problem is in the line:

```
for i in {0..$am..1}
```

Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions. That is, you cannot use a variable in an expression like `{..}`.

Instead, use [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq). With `seq $var` you get a sequence from 1 (default) to `$var`:

```
for i in $(seq "$am")
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly! Thank you, this has been puzzling me for a while.

Comment: Glad to read that :) It is not very obvious unless you've encountered this problem before!

Comment: @CallumWale It's also automatically pointed out if you run [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) on your posted snippet

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that other guy  :) I didn't know such things existed.

Comment: @thatotherguy true and I was about to just post a comment indicating so; but since the solution required some explanation I went all the way to post an answer. Just updated mentioning the website.

Comment: Of course. I just meant it for OP's future convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I'm missing something in that nobody has suggested an arithmetic for loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<am; i++)); do
    …
done
```

This has the particular benefit in bash of being both readable and not requiring a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for i in `seq 0 $((am-1))`
do
...
done
```

Sequence will start from 0 and end at `$am-1`